# Как переписать данные из одного файла в другой, за исключением каждой третьей строки и удалить строку с заданным номером из текстового файла

Tags: python-3.x, работа-с-текстом, текстовые-файлы

Сделал программу для переноса текста с одного файла в другой, но не могу понять, как решить вышеперечисленные задачи. Буду рад, если поможете

````
Lines = file.readlines()
count = 0
nextline = 1
newfile = open("output.txt","+w")
Lines.append('\n')
for line in Lines:
    count += 1
    if nextline == 1:
        newfile.write("{} {} \n".format(count, line.strip()))
    else:
        newfile.write("{} empty \n".format(count))
    if line.find("\n") != -1:
        nextline = 1
    else:
        nextline = 0
    if line.find("\n") == -1:
        break

file.close()
newfile.close()```
````

Comment: Чтобы не считать "вручную" есть специальный метод `for count,line in enumerate(Lines):`

Answer (score 0):

1. Прочитать файл построчно в список (уже сделано).
2. Идти по списку через range(len()) или используя счетчик.
3. Если номер кратный 3 - ничего не делать. Если некратный - добавлять в итоговый список, который потом записать в файл.